# Is Blob read-only (for example in Firefox 6)?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, blob, gecko

Tried to add custom property (name) onto a Blob object, but got no result. As if Blob was read-only. Is it?

**UPDATE**:

```
// file variable populated somewhere here...

var blob = file.mozSlice(0, 256);
blob.name = 'file_name';

// blob.name === undefined
```